# "General::ivar : … is not a valid variable" when derivating in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm facing this problem, I want to derivate an expression with respect to a variable depending on another variable (not the actual expressions I'm using, they're way more long and complex):

```
y := x^2 + x + 1;
z := sqrt[y];
D[z, y]
General::ivar: 1+x+x^2 is not a valid variable.
```

I saw I can solve the problem if I expand the variables like this

```
D[sqrt[1 + x + x^2], x]
```

but for long expressions it doesn't seem viable. Is there a simpler way to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: As an aside, if you want Mathematica to understand `sqrt` use `Sqrt`.  Further, in `D[z,y]` it's not entirely clear whether you want `y` as the second argument or `x`.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I corrected the Sqrt, but still get that error message. What I want is the expression of the derivative of z with respect to y, that is 1/(2*sqrt(y)).

Comment: But you've used `:=` (SetDelayed) to define `y`, which means that whenever you ask for `y` later in the program it is replaced by `x^2 + x + 1` and it seems that Mathematica doesn't like that as the second argument in `D[]`.  Try `D[Sqrt[q],q]` where `q` is any symbol which doesn't already have a value in the workspace.

Comment: Ok, but problem is that I need to combine the different derivatives because I'm working on some transformations between variables.

Comment: Take a look here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135702/12

Comment: @Szabolcs thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are not consistent with your notations. If you replace `D[z, y]` by `D[z, x]`, you will get the desired answer.

```
y := x^2 + x + 1;
z := Sqrt[y];
D[z, x]
```

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want D[z,x], I want D[z,y]. Sqrt is just an example, the actual expressions I'm using are much longer, that's why I used that as an example, but they're still defined one as a function of the other.

Comment: @matteeeo you meant to say that you want to differentiate `z` w.r.t `x^2 + x + 1` not w.r.t `x`?

Comment: Ok, in my script I'm working with some coordinate tranformations, so they're defined sequentially one as a function of the others. I need to combine them, so in some cases I need     D[y,x], in other cases I need       D[z,x], and in others       D[z,y]. My question is: how can I obtain       D[z,y] when       y is already defined as       x^2+x+1 ?